# Erlang Cowboy change server signature in HTTP headers

Tags: http, rest, erlang, cowboy

Can someone tell me how to change default server signature in Erlang Cowboy Framework (which is "Cowboy") to a custom one, in all requests? I mean the value for the key "server" in HTTP response headers.

Kind regards,
Leandro

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to achieve this would be by using [onresponse hook](http://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/HEAD/guide/hooks/)

`cowboy:start_http` accepts a list of arguments in which you can supply `onrequest` and `onresponse hooks`. The basic syntax is very simple. It is just a tuple consisting on an atom and the name of the function.

```
   {onresponse, fun custom_onresponse/4}
```

Within this onresponse function you can modify the headers.  For your special case you want to remove `Server` header. So you custom_onresponse will look like this

```
custom_onresponse(StatusCode,Headers,Body,Req)-> 
                Headers2 = 
                lists:delete({<<"server">>,<<"Cowboy">>},Headers),
                {ok,Req2} = cowboy_req:reply(StatusCode,Headers2,Body,Req),
                Req2.
```

To replace it you can use [keyreplace function](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#keyreplace-4) like so

```
Headers2 = 
lists:keyreplace(<<"server">>,1,Headers,{<<"server">>,<<"Your_Header">>})
```

There is also an example provided in the [examples section](https://github.com/extend/cowboy/blob/master/examples/error_hook/src/error_hook_app.erl) of cowboy repo. Hope this helps.

Comment: Happy to help :) would be great if you could accept this ans an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's illustrated by the [manual entry's](http://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/1.0/guide/resp/#reply) third code fragment.